# SharpDevelop SQLite ironpython not loading

Tags: sqlite, ironpython

Im using SharpDevelop 4.4.2 and trying to build a WPF ironpython aplication and everything works great exept for importing sqlite.
Im using Ironpython 2.7.3

What I have done:
I have added a referance to the IronPython.SQLite.dll in the "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\DLLs" folder.
I then import IronPython.SQLite to the Window.py and when I run the aplication I get a "ImportError: No module named SQLite"

I have tried multiple solutions online including downloading other IronPython.SQLite.dll's

Am I missing something. Please any help would be awesome.

Thank you

Comment: how are you importing the module, with `import sqlite3` ?

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply. I am adding the sqlite3.dll to my references and I am adding the dll to my bin folder. This is so frustrating.

Comment: I finaly got IronPython.SQLite dll running but end up with a new error when I try and connect to db

conn = IronPython.SQLite
conn.connect("Test.db")
this just gives me a "attribute 'connect' of 'namespace#' object is read-only"

I would amuse that I am not referencing the class properly.